# How to get the right source code with Python from the URLs using my web crawler?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler

I'm trying to use python to write a web crawler. I'm using **re** and **requests** module. I want to get urls from the first page (it's a forum) and get information from every url.

My problem now is, I already store the URLs in a List. But I can't get further to get the RIGHT source code of these URLs.

Here is my code:

```
import re
import requests

url = 'http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=forumdisplay&fid=55&typeid=470&sortid=231&filter=typeid&pageNum=1&page=1'

sourceCode = getsourse(url) # source code of the url page
allLinksinPage = getallLinksinPage(sourceCode) #a List of the urls in current page
for eachLink in allLinksinPage:
    url = 'http://bbs.skykiwi.com/' + eachLink.encode('utf-8')
    html = getsourse(url) #THIS IS WHERE I CAN'T GET THE RIGHT SOURCE CODE


#To get the source code of current url
def getsourse(url):
    header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows  NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/8.0; Touch)'}
    html = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    return html.text

#To get all the links in current page
def getallLinksinPage(sourceCode):
    bigClasses = re.findall('<th class="new">(.*?)</th>', sourceCode, re.S)
    allLinks = []
    for each in bigClasses:
        everylink = re.findall('</em><a href="(.*?)" onclick', each, re.S)[0]
        allLinks.append(everylink)
return allLinks
```

Comment: What do you mean by the RIGHT source code of the URL's - can you clarify your problem and include any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define your functions after you use them so your code will error. You should also not be using re to parse html, use a parser like [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) as below. Also use [urlparse.urljoin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) to join the base url to the  the links, what you actually want is the *hrefs* in the *anchor* tags inside the the *div*  with the id `threadlist`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin

url = 'http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=forumdisplay&fid=55&typeid=470&sortid=231&filter=typeid&pageNum=1&page=1'



def getsourse(url):
    header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows  NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/8.0; Touch)'}
    html = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    return html.content

#To get all the links in current page
def getallLinksinPage(sourceCode):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sourceCode)
    return [a["href"] for a in soup.select("#threadlist a.xst")]



sourceCode = getsourse(url) # source code of the url page
allLinksinPage = getallLinksinPage(sourceCode) #a List of the urls in current page
for eachLink in allLinksinPage:
    url = 'http://bbs.skykiwi.com/'
    html = getsourse(urljoin(url, eachLink))
    print(html)
```

If you print `urljoin(url, eachLink)` in the loop you see you get all the correct links for the table and the correct source code returned, below is a snippet of the links returned:

```
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3177846&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3197510&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3201399&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3170748&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3152747&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3168498&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3176639&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3203657&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3190138&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3140191&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3199154&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3156814&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3203435&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3089967&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3199384&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3173489&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3204107&extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231
```

If you visit the links above in your browser you will see it get the correct page, using `http://bbs.skykiwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&amp;tid=3187289&amp;extra=page%3D1%26filter%3Dtypeid%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231%26typeid%3D470%26sortid%3D231` from your results you will see :

```
Sorry, specified thread does not exist or has been deleted or is being reviewed
[New Zealand day-dimensional network Community Home]
```

You can see clearly the difference in the url's. If you wanted yours to work you would need to do a replace in your regex:

```
 everylink = re.findall('</em><a href="(.*?)" onclick', each.replace("&","%26"), re.S)[0]
```

But really don't parse html will a regex.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, especially for making me aware of BeautifulSoup. The first time I have heard that amazing tool! I'm trying to finish the codes using BeautifulSoup. Can you help me to look at the other question please? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546667/is-there-a-better-approach-to-use-beautifulsoup-in-my-python-web-crawler-codes) @Padraic Cunningham